# updating shared prefrences in android

Tags: java, android

well i'm just testing the idea of shared preferences to save the user progress, but this simple code is not working, when i pass lev1 it should update preffile so that at next app start it should opens directly to lev2Activity, everything is ok even log cat is clean but nothing happens, i don't know whats wrong with my code, any help will be appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
private Button b1;
public static final String levstate= "levstate";
private Context mycontext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mycontext= this;
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MainActivity.savelevstate(1, mycontext);
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lev1Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

}




public static void savelevstate(int state, Context mycontext)

{
    SharedPreferences pref= mycontext.getSharedPreferences("preffile", MODE_APPEND);
    Editor editor= pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("levstate", state);
    editor.commit();
}

public static int getlevstate(Context mycontext)

{
    SharedPreferences pref= mycontext.getSharedPreferences("preffile", MODE_APPEND);
    int state= pref.getInt("levstate", 1);

    return state;


}
```

Lev1Activity.java

private EditText et1;
    private Button b1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lev1);

    et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

}

public void Next (View v)

{

    String value= et1.getText().toString();
    int finalvalue= Integer.parseInt(value);

    if(finalvalue==22)

    {
        Intent i = new Intent (this, Lev2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        MainActivity.savelevstate(2, this);
        this.finish();




    }

}
```

Comment: Use `MODE_PRIVATE` instead of `MODE_APPEND` when you retrieve the `SharedPreferences`

Comment: didn't help @Gil Vegliach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of using `sharedPreferences` is excellent. However, if you look at your MainActivity's `onCreate()`, you can see that you never check the last level state before starting the intent. The app runs, the user clicks on button "b1" and it immediately starts `Lev1Activity`. Assuming you want the correct level to start when the user presses that same button, you'd have to check for the current level state and then link that state to its appropriate level Activity.

For example (MainActivity.java):

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i;
        switch(getlevstate(myContext)) {
            case 1:
                i = new Intent(myContext, Lev1Activity.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                i = new Intent(myContext, Lev2Activity.class);
                break;
            case 3:
                i = new Intent(myContext, Lev3Activity.class);
                break;
            case 4
                i = new Intent(myContext, Lev4Activity.class);
                break;
            ...
        }

        startActivity(i);
    }

});
```

Using `MODE_APPEND` should work as well as using `MODE_PRIVATE`, however it is recommended to use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the problem, but when I use Preferences I use  `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` this is the only difference between my code and yours, maybe it will help!

Edit : I might be wrong, but I don't see anywhere the call to `getlevstate`. After setting this

```
et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
```

You shoud do somehing like this :

```
et1.setText(""+getlevstate(this))
```

Comment: tried to use mode private, nothing changes. @liltof

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you to create a new class for working with SharedPreferences.

Here is a example for saving and retrieving data from shared preferences:

```
public class SharedPreferenceSettings {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "MY_APP_SETTINGS";
    private static final String PREFS_LANGUAGE = "LANGUAGE";
    private static final String PREFS_CITY = "CITY";

    private final SharedPreferences settings;

    public SharedPreferenceSettings(Context context) {
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        settings.edit().putString(PREFS_LANGUAGE, language).apply();
    }

    public String getlanguage() {
        return settings.getString(PREFS_LANGUAGE, "english");
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        settings.edit().putString(PREFS_CITY, city).apply();
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return settings.getString(PREFS_CITY, "london");
    }
}
```

For more info, check official Android documentation - [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are only saving the states, but you aren't checking it anywhere in the code.

In `MainActivity` try this :

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(getlevstate(MainActivity.this)==2) {
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lev2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            MainActivity.savelevstate(1, mycontext);
            Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lev1Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

});
```